Editing layers using QWC services
This question is related to the qwc-docker project.
I am trying to make my QGS project layers editable from within the qwc-map-viewer Demo. I've done all the steps listed here and re-checked everything several times.
In addition to those steps I also enabled WFS for the layers in the QGS project.
The postgres user used in the pg_service.conf and qwc-docker/pg_service-write.conf has full rw access to the PostgreSQL database.
However in the end when I run the config generator from the Admin GUI to update the service configuration it doesn't create anything for the "editConfig" property in the volumes/config/default/mapViewerConfig.json file. It remains editConfig: {}
In the Map Viewer when I click the Editing button I simply get the message "No editable layers".
In the docker logs I have no warning or error that would give me some hints as to why I can't make my layers editable.
I don't know what to check anymore, I'm hoping someone already struggled with this and can give me some clues as to how I could debug this.
The host is a Debian 12.7 server, docker 27.2.0, the qwc docker containers are the same versions as those listed in the default docker-compose.yml file in qwc-docker.
My QGIS Desktop project version is 3.38.1.

You need to create Resources and Permissions about the project and the layers you want to edit, as mentioned in the documentation (Quick start). Please check if it is the case.
For instance:

create resource Map for QGIS project "my_project"
create resource Data for layer "my_layer" which parent resource is Map "my_project" and check the box "Write"
create permission for resource Map "my_project" to public role (everyone is allowed to see the project, no need to log in)
create permission for resource Data "my_layer" to public role (everyone is allowed to edit the layer, no need to log in)
generate configuration and you should see some datasets resources in volumes/config/default/dataConfig.json (qwc-data-service) and editConfig in volumes/config/default/mapViewerConfig.json (qwc-map-viewer)


Yeah I had already done that, only exception I had used the admin role instead of public for both the Map and Data resource. I just tried with public and regenerated the config but no change unfortunately. No resource dataset in dataConfig.json and no editConfig in mapViewerConfig.json.

Please check that resources name match to the technical name of its resource (e.g. WMS layer name). You can check WMS layers name by requesting GetCapabilities
